# android parse json object use jsontokener

Tags: java, android, json

I try to parse json use jsontokener
This is my jsontokener code :

```
try {
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(strJson).nextValue();
        String query = jObj.getString("query");
        JSONArray location = jObj.getJSONArray("locations");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dummy_text);
        tv.setText(query);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dummy_text);
        tv.setText("Wrong");
    }
```

this is my first strJson :

```
        String strJson = "{"
             + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\", "
             + "  \"locations\": [ 94043, 90210 ] "
             + "}";
```

and it will show

> Pizza

and i try to change strJson to be like this :

```
        String strJson = "{"
             + "    \"component\":  "
                 + "{"
                    + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\", "
                    + "  \"locations\": [ 94043, 90210 ] "
                 + "}"
             + "}";
```

and it will show

> wrong

That mean code enter to catch.
please help me how to improve my code, so it can get query in component.

Answer (score 1):

finnaly i found the answer, i just improve code to be like this :

```
try {
        JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(strJson).nextValue();
        JSONObject obj = jObj.getJSONObject("component");
        String query = obj.getString("query");
        //JSONArray location = jObj.getJSONArray("locations");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dummy_text);
        tv.setText(query);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dummy_text);
        tv.setText("Wrong");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is no need to use the JSONTokener class directly. This is really only a Helper class to JSONObject. Just create a new JSON object directly from the string

```
try {    
    JSONObject component = new JSONObject(strJson).getJSONObject("component");
    String query = component.getString("query");
    JSONArray locations = component.getJSONArray("locations");
    // Do something ...

} catch( JSONException e) {
    // Do something ...
}
```