# What is the difference between JSONObject and JSONTokener?

Tags: android, json

I'm wondering what is the difference between using a JSONObject and JSONTokener to parse a JSON string.
I have seen examples where either of these classes were used to parse a JSON string.
For example, I parsed a JSON string like this:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();
        return object.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("translations").
                getJSONObject(0).getString("translatedText");
```

But I also see examples where they simply use a JSONObject class (without using JSONTokener) to parse it:

```
String in;
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);
JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("sys");
country = sys.getString("country");
```

I read the description on this [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), but still don't really get the difference. Is one better than the other performance wise and when should a JSONTokener be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question when I read documentation mentioned in question.
While searching I found this,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27457728

> Normally there is no need to use the JSONTokener class directly. This is really only a Helper class to JSONObject.

Also here,
https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONTokener.html

> A JSONTokener takes a source string and extracts characters and tokens from it. It is used by the JSONObject and JSONArray constructors to parse JSON source strings.

So I checked source code here,
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/f2f7880a40aed1c8d9c27db49226e47396556aac/libcore/json/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java

```
/**
* Creates a new {@code JSONObject} with name/value mappings from the JSON
* string.
*
* @param json a JSON-encoded string containing an object.
* @throws JSONException if the parse fails or doesn't yield a {@code
*     JSONObject}.
*/
public JSONObject(String json) throws JSONException {
    this(new JSONTokener(json));
}
```

So *JSONTokener* is used in both cases to parse string values. But which class to use depends on what you want to do. There some more functions in *JSONTokener* such as *nextTo(excluded: Char)*,*skipPast(thru: String!)*,*skipTo(to: Char)* etc to parse only required values.

Answer (score 1):

The `JSONTokener` class allows an application to break a string into tokens. It can be used by the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` constructors to parse JSON source strings.

A few important methods of `JSONTokener` class are:

- `back()`: Moves the cursor one position back
- `more()`: Returns true if the token has an element or else returns false
- `next()`: Returns a character next to current position
- `nextTo(character)`: Returns a string until the given character matches

Syntax:
`public class JSONTokener extends java.lang.Object`